# Is it possible to deploy / publish software on onedrive?

Tags: .net, clickonce, onedrive

With OneDrive, it’s easy to share files securely and easily with other people. They won’t need to install any special programs or sign up for a new account, and they can use any web browser to get to the files you share with them. And you have control—your files will only be shared with the people you choose.

How can I deploy/publish WPF software in OneDrive using click once ? Like we deploy/publish on server.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't when using ClickOnce. The file names / URL's of OneDrive aren't in a format ClickOnce understands.

You could write your own update mechanism to check updates though. That is very well possible. You can use the [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659752.aspx) to access the files, or publish the file paths on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OneDrive API to download installers/updates to a local folder, and then use ClickOnce to deploy from that folder.

I'm doing something similar but with [`Squirrel.Windows`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/squirrel.windows/) and Azure Storage Blobs.